# phpのビルトインウェブサーバーに外部からアクセスが出来ません

Tags: php, slim

現在、macでphpのフレームワークslimを使って、
ビルトインウェブサーバーであるサイトの開発を試みています。

macのブラウザからは、そのサイトにアクセスできるのですが、
iPhoneからはできません。
２週間前は同じ手法でできていたのですが、
二週間いじらなかったら、こうなってました。

## macでサーバー起動

php -S 0.0.0.0:8080

## ifconfigでmacのIPアドレスを確認

192.168.11.3

## macのブラウザでhttp://127.0.0.1:8080にアクセス

普通にサイトが見れる

## 同じネットワークにつながってるiPhoneで192.168.11.3:8080にアクセス

「ページを開けません。Safariはサーバーに接続できませんでした」と表示されます。
そして、サーバーを起動してるターミナルに↓のエラーが出ます。
[Sat Jun  6 21:15:11 2015] 192.168.11.1:3424 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

ちなみに、同じネットワークの別PCから同じURLにアクセスしても、
やはりアクセスできず、↑と同じエラーが出ます。

iPhoneとPCが同じネットワークにつながっていることは確認済みです。

以前は、
そもそもこの方法を知らずに、
外部からアクセスする方法を調べてアクセスできていたのに、
二週間位ぶりに同じ方法をやったらアクセスできませんでした。

他に何か設定がおかしかったり、原因のあたりがつくところがあれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

ターミナルに「Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)」と出るということは、ビルトインサーバへのアクセスは来ているような気がします。

問題を切り分ける為に、まずは slim と関係の無いディレクトリを作成し、echoだけするindex.phpを置いてみて試してみてはいかがでしょうか？echoが表示されるようなら、問題は slim 側の設定や実装にあるかもしれません。

index.php

```
<?php    
echo "Hello, World";
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、確かにサーバーへリクエストは来ているかと。
ご提案くださったように、適当なディレクトリでHelloWorldのindex.phpををphp -Sで動かしてみました。やはり、「ページを開けません。Safariはサーバーに接続できませんでした。」と出ます。ちなみに、PCからアクセスすると、普通にHelloWorldが表示されます、Slim以前の問題のようですね。

Answer (score 0):

Apache や nginx ではいかがでしょうか？

ほかにトンネルサービスの ngrok を使った方法があります。私の環境では動作を確認できました。ngrok を使ったやり方は次のようになります。

最初にコマンドツールの ngrok をインストールしてコマンドラインから実行できるようにします。

次に ngrok のアカウントを作成します。Github や Google アカウントによる Oauth 認証が利用できます。

今度は ngrok のダッシュボードのページ (dashboard) で表示される認証トークンを引数にして次のコマンドを実行します。コピペできるようにコードが表示されています。

```
./ngrok authtoken 認証トークン
```

最後に http サブコマンドを実行してサーバーを公開します。引数にはポート番号を指定します。

```
./ngrok http 8080
```

「Forwarding」の右側にアクセスできる URL が示されるので、ブラウザーでその URL にアクセスしてページが表示されることを確認します。